# KDevelop can't find cmake in /usr/sbin/

Tags: docker, cmake, arm64, kdevelop

I'm following https://develop.kde.org/docs/kirigami/introduction-getting_started/#mainqml (kirigami introduction) to create apps for my pinephone (arch64v8). I'm using KDevelop and have an aarch64 docker container with Arch ARM, which I want to use as a build host.

KDevelop finds the container, but building fails after:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: 
runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/bin/cmake": stat
/usr/bin/cmake: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

cmake is in `/usr/sbin/`, not `/usr/bin`.

I tried changing the cmake location in KDevelop's global CMake configuration, but that didn't help.

I could cymlink cmake in the container, but that's hard to maintain.

How do I tell KDevelop where to find cmake in the container?

Comment: Why would one ever run CMake as root? If that's not what's happening, then why install it to `/usr/sbin`?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution was to remove the ,kdev4 file and reopen the project. Then you get a chance to say where the cmake is.